# WordPress Ajax фильтр

Tags: php, wordpress

Делаю фильтр продуктов на WordPress. Зашел в тупик и не смог найти решение. У меня есть фильтр (скриншот прикрепил). [image: фильтр]

Я создал кастомный тип записи. И у него есть 3 подрубрики Материал/Стиль/Компановка.
И не могу понять как правильно на стороне сервера фильтровать записи. Сейчас если выбрать несколько материалов и стилей. Фильтр выводит все записи у которых есть хотя бы одна из рубрик, а нужно чтоб он выводил только те записи у которых выбраны отмеченные рубрики.
Пробовал делать такой запрос

```
$checkedValues = isset($_GET['checkedValues']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['checkedValues']) : '';

$checkedValues = explode(',', $checkedValues);
$min_price = $_GET['min'] ? $_GET['min']  : 0;
$max_price = $_GET['max'] ? $_GET['max'] : 999999;
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'card_price',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_type'   =>'kitchen',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'card_price',
            'value' => $min_price,
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare' => '>=',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'card_price',
            'value' => $max_price,
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare' => '<=',
        ),
    ),
);
if (!empty($checkedValues) && !empty($checkedValues[0])) {
    $args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            'taxonomy' => 'material',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $checkedValues,
        ),
    );
}
$order = $_GET['order'] ?? '';
if ($order === 'A-z') {
    $args['order'] = 'ASC';
    $args['orderby'] = 'title';
} elseif ($order === 'Z-a') {
    $args['order'] = 'DESC';
    $args['orderby'] = 'title';
}
```

И нашел еще вот такой вариант, но что-то мне подсказывает что это вообще бред

```
if (!empty($checkedValues) && !empty($checkedValues[0])) {
    $args = array(
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'material',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $checkedValues,
            ),
        ),
    );

    if (!empty($checkedValues2) && !empty($checkedValues2[0])) {
        $args['tax_query'][] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'material',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $checkedValues2,
            'operator' => 'EXISTS',
        );
    }

    if (!empty($checkedValues3) && !empty($checkedValues3[0])) {
        $args['tax_query'][] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'material',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $checkedValues3,
            'operator' => 'EXISTS',
        );
    }
}
```

Из фильтра ajax запросом передаются term_id.
Буду очень благодарен за какую-либо помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут простой `WP_Query` только надо прокидывать значения `meta_query` [Вот статья об этом](https://misha.agency/wordpress/meta_query.html). Не надо городить велосипеды, которые нельзя просто обслуживать.